# Why this CUDA kernel gives different result with original code?

Tags: c++, cuda

I ported this piece of code:

```
    if(_layersCount > 1)
    {
        for(int i=_layersCount-2;i>=0;i--)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<_neuronsPerLayerCount[i];j++) // cuda kernel
            {
                localGradients[indexByLayerAndNeuron(i, j)] = 0;

                for(int k=0;k<_neuronsPerLayerCount[i+1];k++)
                {
                    localGradients[indexByLayerAndNeuron(i, j)] += _neuronsInputsWeights[indexByLayerNeuronAndInput(i+1, k, j)]
                                                                    * localGradients[indexByLayerAndNeuron(i+1, k)];
                }

                localGradients[indexByLayerAndNeuron(i, j)] *= derivatives[indexByLayerAndNeuron(i, j)];
            }
        }
    }
```

to CUDA:

```
    if(_layersCount > 1)
    {
        for(int i=_layersCount-2;i>=0;i--)
        {
            // calculateLocalGradientsForAnotherLayers
            blocksCount = floor((double) _neuronsPerLayerCount[i] / threads.x) + 1;
            blocks = dim3(blocksCount, 1);

            calculateLocalGradientsForAnotherLayers <<<blocks, threads>>> (deviceLocalGradients, _neuronsInputsWeights, deviceDerivatives, _neuronsPerLayerCount[i], _neuronsInPreviousLayers[i], _neuronsInPreviousLayers[i+1], _neuronsPerLayerCount[i+1], _inputsInPreviousLayers[i], _inputsInCurrentLayer[i]);
        }
    }
```

The calculateLocalGradientsForAnotherLayers kernel:

```
__global__ void calculateLocalGradientsForAnotherLayers(double * localGradients, double * neuronsInputsWeights, double * derivatives, int neuronsCount, int neuronsInPreviousLayers, int neuronsInPreviousLayersWithCurrent, int neuronsInNextLayer, int inputsInPreviousLayers, int inputsInCurrentLayer)
{
    int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    if(idx < neuronsCount)
    {
        int neuron = neuronsInPreviousLayers + idx;

        localGradients[neuron] = 0;

        // this to Kernel, then reduce localGradients.
        for(int k=0;k<neuronsInNextLayer;k++)
        {
            localGradients[neuron] += neuronsInputsWeights[inputsInPreviousLayers + k*inputsInCurrentLayer + idx]
                                                            * localGradients[neuronsInPreviousLayersWithCurrent + k];
        }

        localGradients[neuron] *= derivatives[neuron];
    }
}
```

But I see the difference in the results from the second decimal place. Why error is so large? All kernels works good except this.

My GPU is NV GF555M. It supports double precision.

Comment: how do you call the kernel? grid/block size.

Comment: See the second code block. threads.x is 512

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the body of your kernel, you need some kind of inter-block synchronization over `localGradients` array:

```
for(int k=0;k<neuronsInNextLayer;k++)
        {
            localGradients[neuron] += neuronsInputsWeights[inputsInPreviousLayers + k*inputsInCurrentLayer + idx]
                                                            * localGradients[neuronsInPreviousLayersWithCurrent + k];
        }
```

Concurrent read/write accesses may destroy the actual value of `localGradients` elements. Since there is no synchronization on the read/write, you may see random results.

Comment: How to add syncronization?

What if I will save this into temp variable and then save in into localGradients[neuron]?

Comment: Let start with your serial code shown in the question body (code block 1). Let me know the `for` loops (i, j, and k) which have independent iterations? Obviously the iterations of `k` loop are dependent. What about `i` and `j` loops?

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I found problem. Instead line:

```
calculateLocalGradientsForAnotherLayers <<<blocks, threads>>> (deviceLocalGradients, _neuronsInputsWeights, deviceDerivatives, _neuronsPerLayerCount[i], _neuronsInPreviousLayers[i], _neuronsInPreviousLayers[i+1], _neuronsPerLayerCount[i+1], _inputsInPreviousLayers[i], _inputsInCurrentLayer[i]);
```

should wrote:

```
calculateLocalGradientsForAnotherLayers <<<blocks, threads>>> (deviceLocalGradients, _neuronsInputsWeights, deviceDerivatives, _neuronsPerLayerCount[i], _neuronsInPreviousLayers[i], _neuronsInPreviousLayers[i+1], _neuronsPerLayerCount[i+1], _inputsInPreviousLayers[i+1], _inputsInCurrentLayer[i+1]);
```